# How to write a better way to cycle through JSON values in react when the data is missing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am quite new of react, and I am designing a "design system" that reads from JSON so that I can drag and drop the application and use it in various project by just modifying the parameters of the data in the JSON.

I have link colors, and normal colors. Links colors can be applied only to text. While Colors can be applied to text and backgrounds.

To visualize the colors available I have created a palette of all the colors used by printing what I am calling as component ColorBox.

[image]

The whole code can be found here: https://github.com/Littlemad/myapp

```js
import React from "react";
import dataJSON from "../../../data/data.json";
import "./ColorBox.scss";

const colorsJSON = dataJSON.colors;
const linksJSON = dataJSON.links;

const ColorBox = (props) => {
    var myColor = colorsJSON.find((e) => e.var === props.var);

    // TODO: revise this, it is not decent code
    if (myColor === undefined) {
        myColor = linksJSON.find((e) => e.var === props.var);
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div className="colorbox">
                <div className="colorbox__name">{myColor.name}</div>
                <div className={`colorbox__color color-bg--${myColor.var}`}></div>
                <div className="colorbox__val">
                    <p>
                        <strong>{myColor.value}</strong>
                    </p>
                    <code>{myColor.var}</code>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default ColorBox;
```

The Json data looks like this

```js
"colors": [
  {"value": "#fff", "var": "white", "name": "White"},
  {"value": "#f5f5f5", "var": "grey-l3", "name": "Very Light Grey"},
  {"value": "#eee", "var": "grey-l2", "name": "Light Grey"},
  {"value": "#ddd", "var": "grey-l1", "name": "Lightish Grey"},
  {"value": "#bbb", "var": "grey", "name": "Grey"},
  {"value": "#999", "var": "grey-d1", "name": "Darkish Grey"},
  {"value": "#666", "var": "grey-d2", "name": "Dark Grey"},
  {"value": "#333", "var": "grey-d3", "name": "Very Dark Grey"},
  {"value": "#000", "var": "black", "name": "Black"},

  {"value": "#68BBE3", "var": "primary-l2", "name": "Baby Blue"},
  {"value": "#0E86D4", "var": "primary-l1", "name": "Blue Grotto"},
  {"value": "#055C9D", "var": "primary", "name": "Blue"},
  {"value": "#003060", "var": "primary-d1", "name": "Navy Blue"},
  {"value": "#001040", "var": "primary-d2", "name": "Dark Navy Blue"},

  {"value": "#390", "var": "success", "name": "Success"},
  {"value": "#fc0", "var": "warn", "name": "Warning"},
  {"value": "#c30", "var": "fail", "name": "Failure"}
],
"links": [
  {"value": "#00c", "var": "link", "name": "Link"},
  {"value": "#a4b", "var": "link-visited", "name": "Link Visited"},
  {"value": "#c30", "var": "link-active", "name": "Link Active"}
]
```

The component are than being called like this

```html
<div className="box">
  <h2 className="h2 bold box__title">Accent</h2>
  <div className="box-palette__grid">
    <ColorBox var="success" />
    <ColorBox var="warn" />
    <ColorBox var="fail" />
  </div>
</div>
<div className="box">
  <h2 className="h2 bold box__title">Link values</h2>
  <div className="box-palette__grid">
    <ColorBox var="link" />
    <ColorBox var="link-visited" />
    <ColorBox var="link-active" />
  </div>
</div>
```

I am assuming because I know what data there is, that with a check if !undefined on the colorsJSON  it means that I have to load the other set of values. I am unable to think of a better way to cycle through the set of data, or how to find a more elegant way to collect the data and just read the part that I am interested.

I am thinking that if in the future I want to add other set of colors to other branch of data (for example only background elements, or only icons colors, or highContrast colors), this will be an issue for sure.

Thank you for your help, any tips on how to improve programming in react would be absolutely appreciated.

p.s. I keep links and colors separated because I am using differently across the design system, so I cannot put them together in the same category.

Comment: Instead of arrays for `colors` and `links` use an object where the object keys are the `var` values.

Comment: Then you access the data you want directly like `myColor = linksJSON[props.var]`.

Comment: could you expand on that? I am interested, but not very clear on how use objects like that. is there a simple example that I could see in action? (could be anything and not related to the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this fits your needs, but if you do need to get rid of the `if` statement and since there is no other check at that point, you could search in the entire concatenated array

So instead of

```
var myColor = colorsJSON.find((e) => e.var === props.var);

if (myColor === undefined) {
    myColor = linksJSON.find((e) => e.var === props.var);
}
```

you can use [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) method and write this

```
var myColor = Object.values(dataJSON).flat().find((e) => e.var === props.var);
```

also this means that you get rid of this too

```
const colorsJSON = dataJSON.colors;
const linksJSON = dataJSON.links;
```

Comment: I like the idea, I just need to read the documentation about what Object and Values does. I am not used to work with objects. From what I understand you are assigning a new object which it get the value of the Json. Wouldn't the parse be long depending on how big is the data? (I have other data in it). Gonna give it a go and let know the result.

Comment: i'm not sure, but since you have already loaded the main json object this will be instant. havent faced such a senario where i had issues with time consuming object operations TBH.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const predicate = (e) => e.var === props.var;
const myColor = colorsJSON.find(predicate) || linksJSON.find(predicate);
```

Comment: Oh cool, didn't know that I could put a condition like that with the OR parameter.

Comment: Yeah, it will go to the right value if the left one is falsy. Downside is you can't use it if you expect a value, like 0 for example. There is another operator called the "nullish coalescing operator", that specifically looks for null or undefined before going to the right value. It looks like this:  [const value = value1 ?? value2].           
I didn't recommend it because you don't really need it in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If you structure your JSON with objects instead of arrays then you can access the data you want to read directly.

```json
"colors": {
  "white": { "value": "#fff", "name": "White" },
  "grey-l3": { "value": "#f5f5f5", "name": "Very Light Grey" },
  etc.
},
"links": {
  "link": { "value": "#00c", "name": "Link" },
  "link-visited": { "value": "#a4b", "name": "Link Visited" },
  etc.
}
```

Now you can `myColor = linksJSON[props.var]`. If you need to convert the `colors` or `links` back to an array for rendering or whatever, you can simply do `Object.keys(JSON.colors)`, or `Object.values(JSON.links)`, etc., whatever best suits your needs.

Comment: Oh, now I get it! I didn't think about this use of the JSON, I have to experiment with it, thank you for the great tip.

Comment: I realised that I have to learn more about Object, there are so many cool properties that I didn't realise that they can be very useful. Thx for showing to me.